# How to quickly create linked list in C/C++ just like java?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

Java has a linked list object which can be used to quickly create a linked list using predefined functions. Does C or C++ have similar libraries too?
I have an upcoming test and I want make the basic list quickly so that I can delve into the real problem. But making these linked lists take so much time! Do I have to switch to java or is there a way?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ stl contains both `singly linkedlist` and `doubly linkedlist`.

> Singly Linkedlist (or Forward List) - > Forward List in c++ stl implenments singly linkedlist.

Example :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<forward_list> 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    forward_list<int> singlyList1; //declaring singly linked list 

    singlyList1.assign({50,40}); // assign values to list
    singlyList1.push_front(60); // insert element at first position

    cout << "The elements forward list are : ";
    for (int&ele : singlyList1)
        cout << ele << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list)

> Doubly Linkedlist (or List) - > list containers are implemented as doubly-linked lists.

Example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main(){

  list<int> dblyList{1,2,3};

  dblyList.push_back(4);
  dblyList.push_front(9);

  cout << "\n Front : " << dblyList.front();
  cout << "\n Back : " << dblyList.back();

   return 0;

}
```

[Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)